# Why do if-let expressions use the assignment operator instead of the equality operator?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to wrap my head around if-let expressions. I know what it does but I can't find the rationale behind some details.

The first detail is the use of the assignment operator instead of the equality operator, and the second one is the placement of the operands.

For example:

```rust
let a = Some(5);

if let Some(i) = a {
    println!("Hello, {}!", i);
}
```

In my head its more "legible" this way:

```rust
if let Some(i) == a {
    println!("Hello, {}!", i);
}
```

Or even better:

```rust
if let a == Some(i) {
    println!("Hello, {}!", i);
}
```

Could someone please help me understand the rationale behind this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Rust syntax is

```
let Some(i) = a
```

because we are *creating a new variable* `i` and initializing it with the wrapped value in `a`. The operator `=` is for creating new variables. You have a pattern on the left hand side, and an expression on the right. All variables on the left, in the pattern, get initialized based on the corresponding values in the expression on the right.

The comparison operator `==` would not make sense here. To say

```
let Some(i) == a
```

would seem to return whether the expression

```
let Some(i)
```

is equal to the expression

```
a
```

When using `==` you expect the left and right hand sides to be complete expressions, that already have values, then you return whether they are equal. But that is not what we are doing in an if-let. When we use if-let we are creating a new variable. `==` only makes sense when the expressions on both sides of it can be evaluated.

Similarly, the expression

```
let a == Some(i)
```

is quite odd, because `a` already exists. We certainly are not creating a new variable `a`. And the same argument against using `==` as before applies, since `i` does not yet exist.

In summary we use `=` when creating a new variable and `==` for testing the equality of expressions (which if they have variables in them, such variables must already exist).

Comment: thank you for your answer, so if let can be interpreted as: if `i` can be constructed from the wrapped value inside `a`, execute the statements inside the if. Yes?

Comment: That is an accurate interpretation, yes. (You also get to say that `i` can be used in the if statement as well, a nice bonus.) `if-let` is actually a shorthand for a `match` on `Option` values. See [this nice example from the Rust By Example book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html)

Comment: Also I agree with the premise of your question. Many programmers are used to seeing `==` in if-conditions, and `=` is sometimes a typo. The exception being reading a chunk of data from a file, assigning it to a variable and immediately comparing it to null, seen e.g. in C and Java, though the assignment would be parenthesized. However it is getting fashionable to do initializations of variables (including via pattern-matching) in if and while conditions and have these new variables be scoped to the statement. It's convenient, for sure, but I agree with you it takes getting used to.